# Enable only first option in a Select Box

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, html-select

I have some "select box" in my page and I don't want to let the user choose any option, but the first (please, don't ask me why). I can't change for 'input' with 'readonly' attribute and I can't remove the options either. I'm sorry for the limitations, but it has to be this way.

I tried this:

```
 $('select').attr('disabled',true);
```

But happens that I don't want to 'loose' the value. I have an ajax call that use those values and when I disable it, the value 'don't exist' anymore.

I tried this too:

```
 $('select').click(function(){
      return false;
 });
```

But without success.

Comment: No need for javascript at all, just disable the options rather than the select

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with one line of code.

```
$('option').attr('disabled','disabled').eq(0).removeAttr('disabled');
```

Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/yaGJc/1/

You can also make use of the `:gt()` greater then selector, although the first one gives more control on which option to have enabled.

```
$('option:gt(0)').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/yaGJc/2/

Answer (score 1):

disable the options with jquery:

```
$('#selector option:gt(0)').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eqcvz/)

Should produce HTML like this:

```
<select multiple>
    <option>test1</option>
    <option disabled>test2</option>
    <option disabled>test3</option>
    <option disabled>test4</option>
    <option disabled>test5</option>
    <option disabled>test6</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this

```
$('.select').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

I fought with this before...

Answer (score 0):

```
var firstValue = $('select:first').val();
$('select:first').attr('disabled', true);
```

Then use the firstValue variable in the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

not sure y u would want to do something like tat but you can try

```
$("select option").each(function (index, obj) {
    if( index > 1 )
        $(obj).attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```